# Webapi POST results in {object} in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to `post` a `string` to a `MVC Controller` and the result is always `{object}` and I am not able to parse\decode\deserialize it. How can I get that string?

C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Foo(dynamic str)
{
    //str always equals to '{object}'
    var path = @"C:\cookieParserXmlOutput\";
}
```

Client code:

```
then((res:any) => {
            let strObj={
                str:res.data
            };
            return this.$http.post("/App/Foo",strObj,{
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
              });

        }).then((res:any)=>{
            return res;
        })
```

Comment: Why `dynamic` and not just `string`?

Comment: `string` results in `null`. I have no idea why....

Comment: Weird. It shoudl not be null as long as you're sure that in browser developer tools you inspected the request and saw it there.

Comment: What is the value of `strObj`?

Comment: @mjwills its just a key value object. Same as `{ "name" : "jon" }`

Comment: I know this has been answered, but since you are passing an object to your API and using `dynamic str` as the server-side parameter, you could have accessed the string value using `str.str`. `dynamic str` takes the form of the object you are passing it so that's why the result was `{object}`. You simply needed to access the `str` property on the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send an `object` in `POST` body, you should also retrieve `object` in ASP.NET Endpoint method. Wrap your `string str` into a `class`:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public string Str { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public void Foo(MyRequest request)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: That was the trick. Many thanks, learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

Change the content type to `text/plain` and convert the object to the string using `JSON.stringify`

```
return this.$http.post("/App/Foo",JSON.stringify(strObj),{
      headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8" }
});
```

Comment: I tried with Postman changing the type to text/plain, still same result

Comment: Same thing, `{object}`